Why $\phi_{*0}(\frac{d}{dt}|_0)=\frac{d\phi^{\mu}(t)}{dt}|_0\frac{\partial}{\partial g^{\mu}}|_e$?
Let $G$ be a Lie group and $\phi :\mathbb{R}\to G$ be a smooth homommorphism. I know that $\phi_{*0}:T_0 \mathbb{R}\to T_eG$ is a linear map, $T_0 \mathbb{R}=\langle \frac{d}{dt}|_0\rangle $, and $T_e G=\langle \frac{\partial}{\partial g^{\mu}}|_e\rangle$. Why $\phi_{*0}(\frac{d}{dt}|_0)=\frac{d\phi^{\mu}(t)}{dt}|_0\frac{\partial}{\partial g^{\mu}}|_e$?
I know that $\phi_{*0}(\frac{d}{dt}|_0)\in T_e G$ and is generated by $\frac{\partial}{\partial g^{\mu}}|_e$ but I don't know that why the coefficients are like these.

It's just the chain rule and the definition of the pushforward. Things are easier to see if you give the resulting vector in $T_eG$ some function $f$ in $C^k(G)$ to act on. We will have;
$$\phi_{*}\bigg(\frac{d}{dt}\bigg|_0\bigg)(f):=\frac{d}{dt}(f\circ\phi)\big|_0$$
$$=\frac{\partial f}{\partial g^{\mu}}\bigg|_{\phi(0)}\cdot\frac{d(g^{\mu}\circ\phi)}{dt}\bigg|_0$$
Because $\phi$ is a homomorphism we will, of course, have that $\phi(0)=e_{{\\}_{G}}$ and our expression becomes;
$$\phi_{*}\bigg(\frac{d}{dt}\bigg|_0\bigg)(f)=\frac{d(g^{\mu}\circ\phi)}{dt}\bigg|_0\cdot\frac{\partial}{\partial g^{\mu}}\bigg|_{e_{{\\}_{G}}}(f)$$
Removing the test function then yields;
$$\phi_{*}\bigg(\frac{d}{dt}\bigg|_0\bigg)=\frac{d(g^{\mu}\circ\phi)}{dt}\bigg|_0\cdot\frac{\partial}{\partial g^{\mu}}\bigg|_{e_{{\\}_{G}}}$$

Thank you very much for your nice explanation. I got it well. Appreciate your help.

Dear @Volk Could you please help me about a similar question? I want to prove that if $F:G\to H$ is a Lie homomorphism, then $F_{*e}(\frac{d\phi (t)}{dt}|{t=0})=\frac{d(F\circ \phi)(t)}{dt}|{t=0}$ where $\phi :\mathbb{R}\to G$ is a smooth homomorpism such that $\phi (0)=e$. Thank you.

@Mahtab That would be a little long for a comment but you can arrive at the answer by realizing that $F_\phi_(v)=(F\circ\phi)_*(v)$.

Dear @Volk , sorry I just got it. You are right. Thank you very very much.
